# Properties of orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

> Let $u$ and $v$ be orthogonal 3d unit vectors. Let $w = u \times v$ and
>
> $$ A=\begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\ v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ w_1 & w_2 & w_3\end{bmatrix}$$ Which of following are correct?
>
> **a.** $A^{-1} = A^T$
> **b.** $\det (A) = 1$
> **c.** The spectrum of $A$ contain $1$ or $-1$

Choices are {a} or {a,b} or {a,b,c}.

---

About (a), $A^T$ is orthogonal, so $AA^T=I$. thus $A^{-1}=A^T$.  **TRUE**
About (b), det(A) is 1 or -1.  **FALSE**

What confuses me is (c).
$AA^T=I$, so $AA^T$ has a eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of 1. thus $\sqrt{\lambda_i}=1$ which leads to $|\lambda_i|=1$.

Could $|\lambda_i|$ not contain 1 or -1 which means (c) is **FALSE**?

Comment: Your answer for (b) is incorrect. Consider the interpretation of $\det(A)$ as the volume of a paralellepiped, or the implications of (a) being true.

Comment: Isn't area equal to |det| ?

Comment: It’s the volume in this case, since you’re working in three dimensions. The sign of the determinant tells you something important, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix, where $n>2$, must be of absolute value $1$, because if $Ax=\lambda x$, then $\|x\|=\|Ax\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$, hence $|\lambda|= 1$. ($\|x\|=\|Ax\|$ follows from the orthogonality of $A$).
When $n=3$ there is always a real eigenvalue, so it must be $\pm 1$. Other eigenvalues can be complex valued, in which case they need not be $\pm 1$, but their absolute value is still $1$, which means that they lie on the boundary of the unit disk in the complex plane, that is, they have the form $e^{i\theta}$ for some real $\theta$.

For $n=2$ it is possible that no eigenvalues exist. The geometry of the real plane allows rotations which keep no direction fixed. For example, the map sending $(x,y)$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-y,x+y)$ is an orthogonal transformation that has no eigenvalues, because there is not even one direction that is not rotated away.

Comment: That's assuming $\lambda$ is real.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: But it doesn't need to be real.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean (c) is FALSE because $\lambda$ could be complex and there's no guarantee 1 or -1 are included in eigenvalues?

Comment: And could you speak more about the case where n=2?

Comment: @nik - Yes, some of the eigenvalues can be complex, and there's no guarantee they will be $1$ or $-1$.